# Python multiprocessing: retrieve next result

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I'm trying to figure out a good way to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) package in Python 3.6 to run a set of around 100 tasks, with a maximum of 4 of them running simultaneously.  I also want to:

1. repeatedly reap the next completed task from the pool and process its return value, until all tasks have either succeeded or failed;
2. make exceptions thrown in any given task non-fatal, so I can still access the results from the other tasks.

I don't need to maintain the order of tasks submitted to the pool (i.e. I don't need a queue).  The total number of tasks ("100" above) isn't prohibitively huge, e.g. I don't mind submitting them all at once and letting them be queued until workers are available.

I thought that [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) would be a good fit for this, but I can't seem to find a "get next result" method that I can call iteratively.

Is this something I'm going to have to roll myself from process management primitives?  Or can `Pool` (or another thing I'm missing) support this workflow?

For context, I'm using each worker to invoke a remote process that could take a few minutes, and that has capacity to handle N jobs simultaneously ("4" in my concretized example above).

Comment: http://pyvideo.org/search.html?q=multiprocessing

Comment: @wwii is there some video in particular you recommend that addresses the question?

Comment: Only in general - I find  the video's of Pycon talks pretty informative. Also the examples given in the [multiprocessing module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) seem to be enough to get me started when I want to play around and experiment.

Comment: This is not directly supported. Such workflow would need some kind of buffer implicitly to hold the results until they are retrieved. So instead using a `Queue` explicitly is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following pattern (shown using 2 workers & 6 jobs, instead of 4 & 100):

```
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
from queue import Queue


def worker(x):
    print("Start: {}".format(x))
    time.sleep(5 * random.random())  # Sleep a random amount of time
    if x == 2:
        raise Exception("Two is bad")
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        jobs = Queue()
        for i in range(6):
            jobs.put(pool.apply_async(worker, [i]))

        while not jobs.empty():
            j = jobs.get(timeout=1)
            try:
                r = j.get(timeout=0.1)
                print("Done: {}".format(r))
            except TimeoutError as e:
                jobs.put(j)  # Not ready, try again later
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception: {}".format(e))
```

Seems to work pretty well:

```
Start: 0
Start: 1
Start: 2
Done: 1
Start: 3
Exception: Two is bad
Start: 4
Start: 5
Done: 3
Done: 4
Done: 5
Done: 0
```

I'll see whether I can make a general utility to manage the queueing for me.

The main shortcoming I think it has is that completed jobs can go unnoticed for a while, while uncompleted jobs are polled and possibly time out.  Avoiding that would probably require using callbacks - if it becomes a big enough problem, I'll probably add that to my app.

Comment: You shouldn't queue the jobs but the results. For the `callback` parameter of `apply_async` you can set a function which puts the result into a queue. A separate thread can then `get` the results sequentially.